# What's the purpose of azure-pipeline.yml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have read some tutorials about Azure DevOps. There are 3 things i do not really understand:

- Can we say azure-pipeline.yml on Azure is the equivalent of .gitlab-ci.yml on gitlab ?
- I have read some tutorials talking about azure-pipeline.yml files and others talking about azure-pipelines.yml ? What is the good syntax for this file name ?
- I have create a "devops project" from Azure Services page. I have choose ASP.Net Core Application and Windows Web App. I can see a pipeline on dev.azure.com but there is no yml file in source code. So i am wondering where is this file...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question in the same order they were asked.

1. Yes, azure-pipeline.yml is the equivalent of gitlab-ci.yml. In both cases you bundle together a number of commands you want to execute.
2. It is the same. The file is called azure-pipelines.yml. Good thing if you try to edit the file in azure-devops is that there is a really nice check and auto-completion tool, that helps a lot especially in indentation (spaces before the command)which is a common issue with yaml files.
   [image]
3. If you created the Ci/CD pipelines by the development center in azure portal you see a UIed version of the yaml. But for every step you can still see the yaml code if you wish. If you try to create a new build pipeline the default way you get is to use the yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

Can we say azure-pipeline.yml on Azure is the equivalent of .gitlab-ci.yml on gitlab

*YAML defines the way to code your configuration management by defining build and release pipelines in the code.It is named as azure-pipelines in Azure Devops  and .gitlab-ci.yml on gitlab*

have read some tutorials talking about azure-pipeline.yml files and others talking about azure-pipelines.yml ? What is the good syntax for this file name ?

*azure-pipelines.yml is the default name, but if you need you canhange the name of the yaml file by clicking on "Edit in the visual designer".*

I have create a "devops project" from Azure Services page. I have choose ASP.Net Core Application and Windows Web App. I can see a pipeline on dev.azure.com but there is no yml file in source code. So i am wondering where is this file...

*There are two ways to create the pipeline one is using the classic editor and using the YAML code. It should definitely be there if you create it using YAML*